# python-Can't use modules installed by Homebrew?

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, virtualenv

I want to use the [essentia](https://github.com/MTG/essentia) module in my python `virtualenv` and the version of python is `2.7.6`.
After I executed

```
 brew tap MTG/essentia
```

I can't find this module in my Pycharm.

I've also tried to install other package such as `matplotlib` using

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

under my virtualenv path.

```
The directory '/Users/username/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/username/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): matplotlib in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.5 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): tornado in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing>=1.5.6 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)
Collecting nose (from matplotlib)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading nose-1.3.7-py2-none-any.whl (154kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 155kB 46kB/s
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): backports.ssl-match-hostname in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): singledispatch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): certifi in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): backports-abc>=0.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from singledispatch->tornado->matplotlib)
Installing collected packages: nose
Successfully installed nose-1.3.7
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I checked in Pycharm, however, in the interpreter there was no `matplotlib` module.
How can I install packages in my virtualenv?

Comment: What do you mean _it didn't work_?  If there was an error such as `Permission denied`, you should use `sudo pip install matplotlib` instead.  If there was a different error, it would require a different answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not install python modules with `brew`, instead you should use `pip`. The following method has worked for me in OSX.

```
Desktop     $ virtualenv myproject # Create the virtual environment
Desktop     $ cd myproject # Change into that directory
Desktop     $ source bin/activate # Enter the virtual environment
(myproject) $ sudo pip install matplotlib # Install matplotlib
(myproject) $ deactivate # Exit from the virtual environment
```

Look [here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/virtual_environment.html) for a further explanation of `virtualenv`.

Comment: `source: no such file or directory: bin/active` after `source bin/active`?

Comment: Make sure you change into the project's directory. For me I would do `cd myproject` after creating it. It should work on Windows, OSX and Linux.

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't  really solved the problem. I'm trying to install the package by compiling the source code under the global environment because the document of the library doesn't provide pip install method.

Comment: As @penguin-penpen said, not all packages can be installed with pip. Essentia is currently only available as a brew formula for python.

Comment: I agree with @Connor. This does not help if a package is not available on pip.

Answer (score 3):

If the pip package is not available, you can find the brew installation in your local python directory.

**Quick Fix:**

- Install essentia to your local environment.
- Append the local essentia package to your virtual environment

`sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
import essentia`

**Long Fix:**

- If you want to fully contain the packages in your virtual environment, try copying the local site-packages/essentia folder to your virtual environment
- Copy over any other dependencies such as site-packages/numpy. Check brew's Cellar (/usr/local/Cellar) for other dependencies

Comment: Hey, I brew-installed a package and I want to be able to import it with python3 from jupyter notebook installed with `pip`. I am not using any virtual environments. How can I solve this problem? In the directory "/usr/local/Cellar/open-babel" I have bin, include, share and lib. Which ones should I copy to "/usr/local/bin/python3/site-packages"?